# Variables de entorno en comandos del package.json en Nuxt

Tags: nuxt

tengo una duda, se pueden utilizar variables de entorno, en los scripts del pacakge.json

```
"cf-export":"contentful space export --config contentful/export-config.json --management-token NUXT_TOKEN --space-id NUXT_SPACE_ID"
```

Donde NUXT_TOKEN y NUXT_SPACE_ID son variables de entorno en el archivo .env